# Name of a tree with arbitrary number of branches at each fork point?

Tags: graphs, terminology

A binary tree is a rooted tree with the root having an indegree of 0 and all other nodes of 1. The outdegree is 0, 1 or 2 for all nodes.

[image: Binary tree - root with 2 branches, which branch once/twice themselves]

How do you call a rooted tree if the **number of branches per node is arbitrary** (outdegree of *n*) but the indegree 1 for all nodes other than the root node?

[image: Tree with four branches and 0-3 sub-branches]

Comment: How is this different from an arbitrary rooted tree?

Comment: The illustration shows what I would consider a _mono-hierarchical_ rooted tree. An arbitrary rooted tree could also be a _poly-hierarchy_ as far as I understand, with some nodes having an indegree > 1 i.e. multiple parents. Would _mono-hierarchical rooted tree_ be understood in the field of computer science / discrete mathematics or are there any other established terms?

Comment: In a rooted tree, every vertex other than the root has a single parent. That's the definition.

Comment: What term would you suggest for the poly-hierarchy case if it's not a tree by definition? Poly-hierarchical rooted _graph_? If one assumes a directed graph with all edges pointing either up or down, then _directed acyclic graph (DAG)_ seems also fitting, as long as there is no edge pointing to any of the (grand)parents.

Comment: I have never heard of poly-hierarchical rooted graphs, but they correspond to Hasse diagrams of posets. So perhaps *Hasse diagram* is a reasonable name, though you'll have to define it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Rooted Tree

> How do you call a rooted tree if the number of branches per node is arbitrary (outdegree of n) but the indegree 1 for all nodes other than the root node?

That is none other than an rooted tree itself or, more accurately, [an arborescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory)) or branching tree or out-tree according to the following quote from [Wikipedia entry on rooted tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Rooted_tree).

> A rooted tree is a tree in which one vertex has been designated the root. The edges of a rooted tree can be assigned a natural orientation, either away from or towards the root, in which case the structure becomes a directed rooted tree. When a directed rooted tree has an orientation away from the root, it is called an arborescence, branching, or out-tree; when it has an orientation towards the root, it is called an anti-arborescence or in-tree.

### Multitree

Your are also interested in what you might call "Poly-hierarchical rooted graph".

> An arbitrary rooted tree could also be a poly-hierarchy as far as I understand, with some nodes having an indegree > 1 i.e. multiple parents.

However, since every vertex other than the root has a single parent in a rooted tree by definition, it is not a viable idea to call them "Poly-hierarchical rooted tree". The conventional name for them is [multitree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitree) as illustrated below, thanks to Wikipedia.

> [image: wikimedia multitree]
>   
>   A multitree may describe either of two equivalent structures: a directed acyclic graph in which the set of nodes reachable from any node form a tree, or a partially ordered set that does not have four items $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ forming a diamond suborder with $a\le b \le d$ and $a\le c \le d$ but with $b$ and $c$ incomparable to each other (also called a diamond-free poset).

### Polytree

You might be interested in [polytree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytree), as illustrated below, thanks to Wikipedia again. It is "also known as oriented tree or singly connected network". It is "a directed acyclic graph whose underlying undirected graph is a tree."

[image: wikimedia ploytree]

### Hasse Diagram

Another related concept is [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram), which is "used to represent a finite partially ordered set, in the form of a drawing of its transitive reduction", as illustrated below.

[image: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819254/how-many-rows-will-we-draw-in-hasse-diagram]

---

**Exercise 1**. Draw a polytree that is not a rooted tree. Draw a multitree that is not a polytree. Draw a Hasse diagram that is not a multitree.

**Exercise 2**. Every rooted tree is a polytree. Show that every polytree is a multitree. Show that every multitree is the Hasse diagram of some finite partially ordered set.

Comment: For exercise 1, also draw a directed acyclic graph that is not a Hasse diagram. For exercise 2, add "every Hasse diagram is a directed acyclic graph".